# How do I make the current version of Ruby the default

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have used RVM to change version 2.0.x to 2.1.3, yet when I restart the term, or my computer, it reverts back to 2.0.x . How do I prevent this?

+++ EDIT

Ok so I guess I have chruby. Will these not work together. and If not, which one should I use?
RVM seems easier.

Comment: Just letting you know that the current stable version is 2.1.4

Comment: Thank you. I will be sure to check that out

Comment: We can't tell you which one to use, that's for you to decide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ rvm use 2.1.3 --default
```

See [Setting the default Ruby](http://rvm.io/rubies/default).